# Prevent default sorting inserted unimplemented methods in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

When Eclipse adds unimplemented methods from an abstract class, it sorts them by name.  That's a problem with method names such as `onBefore` and `onAfter`, which get inserted in a reversed logical order, i.e, `onAfter`, then `onBefore`.  Is there a way to change this behavior in Eclipse?

Comment: Why is it a Problem?

Comment: They're not in logical order, so to be more precise it would be useful to have them inserted in the same order as they appear in the super class, which would be very useful when there's a lot of these type of "event" methods...grouping related methods together makes more sense.

Comment: @user2161989: For clarifications like your comment above it's often good to edit the question text include the clarification. That way readers see the information faster.

Comment: The problem is that the order the methods appear in the super class is only something that exists in the source code. If you look at Class.getMethods(), you will see that "The elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any particular order". So unless Eclipse is analyzing source, which it probably is not, you're probably SOL

Comment: Eclipse doesn't sort methods by its name, if you add abstract class while creating the implementation class and checks the option to implement "Inherited abstract methods".